# How does this code to create an array of sequential numbers work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found this code online and it works; however, I can't work out how!

Can anyone please explain how this code works?

```js
const arr_seq = Array.apply(null, {
  length: 10
}).map(Number.call, Number);

console.log(arr_seq)
```

Output is:

```json
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Also, can anyone explain why this code, which I thought might do exactly the same thing, instead creates an array filled with `undefined`?

```js
const arr_undef = Array(n).map(Number.call, Number);
```

Comment: Hint: `console.log(Array(5));` and then `console.log(Array.apply(null, { length: 5 }));`. You'll see that the first creates an array with 5 empty slots, the second creates an array with `undefined` at each index.

Comment: Second hint: `Array(5).forEach((_, i) => console.log(i))` doesn't print anything.

Comment: @JaredSmith Aha, I tried that and both logged out an array filled with undefined.  But, I was running it in jsbin! I just ran it in node and saw the first creates an empty array, so, of course the .map sparse handling behaviour kicks in. That's what confused me!

Comment: @JaredSmith Yes, I also wrote one using `.map((_,i) => i)` which, personally I prefer as it's clearer what's going on and gives you more control over what sequence fills the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.apply` expects an array(-like) value for its second argument. It will then create an argument for each slot in this array-like object.

Since this code passes `{ length: 5 }` as argument, the `apply` method will call `Array` with 5 values. But when reading `{ length: 5 }[i]` for `i` in the range 0..4, it will always get `undefined`. So `Array.apply(null, { length: 5 })` will translate to `Array(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined)`.

Then the `.map` call has a second argument, which is the `thisArg` argument. This ensures that not just `call` is called, but `Number.call`, i.e. with the right `this` setting. With `Number.call` the first argument will receive those `undefined` values (explained in the previous paragraph) and as **second** argument, the index of the mapping. So we get these calls:

```
Number.call(undefined, 0)
Number.call(undefined, 1)
Number.call(undefined, 2)
Number.call(undefined, 3)
Number.call(undefined, 4)
```

This gives the same result as:

```
Number(0)
Number(1)
Number(2)
Number(3)
Number(4)
```

And `.map` will return an array with those values.

#### Newer ways to do this

Since ECMAScript 2015, JavaScript has `Array.keys()` and spread syntax for array literals. So we can now achieve the same in a less cryptic way:

```js
console.log([...Array(5).keys()]);
```

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks. I didn't know `.map` can take a second argument. And using the first argument of `Number.call` to /dev/null the undefined values is cunning and definitely cryptic. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`Array(n)` creates an empty array of length 10; the `map`/`Number.call` part requires something to be there to get the index:

```js
const arr = Array(5).fill(null).map(Number.call, Number);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, that makes a bit more sense now.